# In Indiana's footsteps

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

[image]

Cross the chasm and pick up all gold coins along the way. Red tiles break away when you step off them.

Comment: "Red tiles break away you step off them." Feels like that's missing a word...

Comment: As you have already been told by mods on this site if you are affiliated with Codex Enigmatum 'In this case, the big notice at the bottom is frankly too much, and makes this as much an advertisement as a puzzle. That's not really what PSE is for. I've cropped it out, but if you want to add some text explaining where the puzzle comes from -- and disclosing your affiliation, if any! -- then that would be fine. (More than fine: there should be some such text. But I couldn't add it and be sure of getting it right, because e.g. I don't know whether the puzzle is actually in the book.'

Comment: @gabbo1092 I believe I had already omitted the notice/link in this image? Anyway, I now also removed the text to be sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if I'm missing something but I think this works.

> [image]

Comment: That's what I had too

Comment: Whoops, didn’t see this when I posted, I’m mobile atm lol

Answer (score 1):

Directions (starting at the top left):

> RRRDDDRUUURRDLLDDURDRR

R = right
U = up
D = down
L = left

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding of the puzzle is correct there are multiple solutions:

> [image]  [image]